# My loop to find the smallest element in an array outputs 0 instead of the correct value x86 Assembly?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86

I am trying to make a program to find the second smallest element in an array. Before I start to find the second smallest element, I am attempting to find the first smallest element in the array. In my program it correctly swaps the lowest element of the array in eax. After it reads the next element in the array, it swaps 0 into eax, despite having no 0 at all in my array. I tried many different combinations, but none of which has made a difference. Here is the code

```
INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
 nbrArray dword 23, 45, 21, 78, 95 dup(?)
 smallest dword 7FFFFFFFh
 secondSmall dword 7FFFFFFFh


 string BYTE 40 DUP (?)
 resultLbl BYTE "The answer is : ", 0
 answer BYTE 40 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
mov eax, smallest
mov edx, secondSmall
mov ebx,0
lea ebx, nbrArray
mov ecx, 5
jecxz end1

forLoop1:
cmp eax, [ebx]
mov edx,[ebx]
jg swap
jmp cont

cont:
 add ebx,4
 loop forLoop1

swap:
 mov eax,[ebx]
 add ebx,4
 loop forLoop1  

 dtoa answer, eax
 output resultLbl, answer
 end1:
    mov eax, 0
    ret

_MainProc ENDP
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`95 dup(?)` means 95 repeats of `0`.**  Use your debugger to dump the memory for your array.  It's the same as `dword 23, 45, 21, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...`

So the last count does a swap of 0 and falls through to the `dtoa`.  Otherwise your program would crash.

---

You have another serious bug: If the last element isn't a new smallest, the `loop forLoop1` falls through from `cont` to `swap` with ECX = 0.  So the `loop` instruction at the bottom of `swap` will decrement ECX to `0xFFFFFFFF` and jump because that's not zero.  You will eventually fault for an out-of-bounds memory access.

`jmp cont` is useless right before the `cont:` label: execution already falls through to the next instruction.  What you need is a `jmp out_of_loop` after the loop branch in the `cont:` block, so you don't fall through into `swap:`.

And BTW, the `loop` instruction is slow, you should never use it.  Just use `cmp/jb` on the pointer you're already incrementing, or `dec ecx/jnz`.